# How to copy single file to every sub folder in Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need your help in writing a google script. I am trying to copy single readme.txt file to all folders and sub folders of a defined folder in my gdrive.

Comment: You need to use a recursive function for walking through all of the folders and sub folders. Take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60419574/7215091

Answer (score 0):

```
var function copyFile() {
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('your folder id');
  getFnF(folder);
}


function getFnF(folder) {
  var srcFile=DriveApp.getFileById('your file id');
  var subfolders=folder.getFolders() 
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder=subfolders.next();  
    srcFile.makeCopy(srcFile.getName(),subfolder);
     getFnF(subfolder); 
  }
}
```